# drawImage() create blured image

Tags: performance, canvas

I'm sorry to ask this question which was posted several times but others responses about blured images don't help me to resolve blur issue.

So i am able to zoom in/out in a canvas with scroll using drawImage().
In my project i use PIXI but i get the same issue.

I noticed that putting an image instead of a canvas in drawImage() there is less blur. I should use canvas because i would like to add graphics on it.

result drawImage() with image
[image]

result drawImage() with canvas
[image]

Here is demo: https://jsfiddle.net/wyllisMonteiro/0dvfe1a3/

Code :

```
var image = new Image();
var canvas = document.createElement( "canvas" );
var src = "https://www.maisons-elytis-lyonouest.fr/wp-content/uploads/Maison-M.-ST-GENIS-LES-OLLIERES-HD-3.jpg";
var isZoomIn = false;

$( document ).ready( function() {

    // load image
    image.addEventListener( "load", function() {

    // create canvas which store image
        canvas.setAttribute( "id", "test" );
        canvas.width = $( window ).width()-5;
        canvas.height = $( window ).height()-5;

        var context = canvas.getContext( "2d" );
        context.imageSmoothingEnabled       = true;
        context.mozImageSmoothingEnabled    = true;
        context.webkitImageSmoothingEnabled = true;

        context.clearRect( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height );
        context.drawImage( image, 0, 0, canvas.width * 1, canvas.height * 1 );

        document.body.append( canvas );

        // Not usefull for the issue
        $( "#test" ).on( "click", function() {
            var ctx = canvas.getContext( "2d" );
            ctx.fillStyle = "green";
            ctx.fillRect(10, 10, 100, 100);
        } );
    } )
    image.src = src;

    document.addEventListener( 'mousewheel', zoomIn );
    document.addEventListener( 'DOMMouseScroll', zoomIn )

    function zoomIn( e ) {
    // define up or down scroll
        var e = window.event || e; // old IE support
        var canvasCtx = e.target.getContext( "2d" );
        var delta = Math.max( -1, Math.min( 1, ( e.wheelDelta || -e.detail ) ) );

        if( delta == 1 ) {
            if( !isZoomIn ) {
               $( "#test" )[0].getContext( "2d" ).drawImage( $( "#test" )[0], -canvas.width / 2, -300, canvas.width * 2, canvas.height * 2 );
               isZoomIn = true;
            }
        } else {
        isZoomIn = false;
            $( "#test" )[0].getContext( "2d" ).drawImage( image, 0, 0, canvas.width * 1, canvas.height * 1 );
        }
    }

} )
```

Comment: Please try `context.imageSmoothingEnabled  = true;`instead of `context.imageSmoothingEnabled  = false;` ( There is also one for moz, and one for webkit: change all of them to true)

Comment: thank you i will try it

Comment: There are no differences

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you noticed is perfectly simple to explain:

When you do draw from the canvas, you are actually resizing a shrinked version of the original image, where pixels have been removed. While when you draw the original image, all pixels are still available to perform the zoom-in.

So obviously, you'll see more artifacts when using the degraded version that is currently painted on the canvas.

To circumvent this, you can keep a copy of your canvas with the full quality of your image painted on it, and do the drawing operations on this full-quality canvas.
Then, you'll be able to draw this full-quality canvas back on the visible canvas, at any zoom level.

```js
var out = output.getContext('2d'); // the canvas we will see
// create an 'offscreen' canvas
// it will store our high quality scene
var offscreen = document.createElement('canvas');
var off = offscreen.getContext('2d');

// 'img' won't get used anymore out of 'begin'
var img = new Image();
img.onload = begin;
img.src = "https://www.maisons-elytis-lyonouest.fr/wp-content/uploads/Maison-M.-ST-GENIS-LES-OLLIERES-HD-3.jpg";

var zoomed = false;
var mousedown = false;
var rad = 20;
var grad = off.createRadialGradient(rad/2, rad/2, rad, rad/2, rad/2, 0);
grad.addColorStop(0.2, 'transparent');
grad.addColorStop(1, 'gold');

function begin() {
  // first draw at full quality
  offscreen.width = img.width;
  offscreen.height = img.height;
  off.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  off.fillStyle = grad;
  off.globalCompositeOperation = 'lighter';
  // then draw to the visible canvas
  drawToMain();
}
function drawToMain() {
  // draw our full quality canvas on the distorted, visible one
  if(zoomed) {
    // uniform scale + translate
    out.setTransform(2,0,0,2,-output.width/2, -output.height/2);
  }
  else {
    out.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
  }
  out.drawImage(offscreen, 0, 0, output.width, output.height);
}

function drawDot(x, y) {
  // we will draw on the offscreen canvas
  // so we need to convert the visible canvas coordinates
  // to the ones of our normal sized 'offscreen' canvas
  var ratio_x = offscreen.width / output.width;
  var ratio_y = offscreen.height / output.height;
  if(zoomed) {
    // apply the camera transforms
    // and non uniform scale (output distortion)
    off.setTransform(ratio_x / 2, 0,0,ratio_y / 2,0,0);
    x += (output.width / 2);
    y += (output.height / 2);
  }
  else {
    // simply distort our offscreen context by setting its scale factor
    off.setTransform(ratio_x, 0, 0, ratio_y, 0, 0);
  }
  // draw a dot.
  // Note that for such a drawing, you'd be better even redraw from scratch every time
  // instead of keeping an offscreen canvas
  // but for demo purposes...
  off.beginPath();
  off.arc(x, y, (rad * (+zoomed + 1)), 0, Math.PI*2);
  off.translate(x - rad /2, y - rad / 2);
  off.fill();
  // render our offscreen canvas on the visible one
  drawToMain();
}

check.onchange = function toggleZoom() {
  zoomed = !zoomed;
  drawToMain();
};

output.onmousemove = function mousemovehandler(evt) {
  if(mousedown) {
    var rect = output.getBoundingClientRect();
    drawDot(evt.clientX - rect.left, evt.clientY - rect.top);
  }
};
output.onmousedown = function mousedownhandler(evt) {
  mousedown = true;
  output.onmousemove(evt);
};
output.onmouseup = function() {
  mousedown = false;
}
```

```html
<label>zoom<input type="checkbox" id="check"></label><br>
click and drag to draw dots on the canvas<br>
<canvas id="output" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank's for explanation that confirm what i thought but as i said to @Helder Sepulveda i can't use image in drawImage() because i created functions to create blur in canvas and i should keep modifications in a canvas. I put update at top in a few moments.

Comment: @WMonteiro read again my answer. What I am drawing is a canvas element. The trick is that all the drawings are made on the offscreen (and unscaled) canvas rather than on the visible (and scaled) one. This way, we always keep the full quality available. You can draw on this canvas by dragging over it, so you see it is indeed the canvas that gets drawn.

Comment: thank you very much it seems to work well but i've a last question. Zoom is enabled by clicking on input but i want to zoom with mousewheel. So can you explain me how does drawMain() and drawDot works? To do what i want should i change ratio of drawDot or should i change drawToMain() function. Thank you, you're genius

Comment: You were using a Boolean to know when to draw zoomed or not, I just changed the way this Boolean is set, but the logic is the same as yours. drawToMain is the function that draws the high-quality to the visible canvas; it's this one you'll want to call when your zoom boolean changes, (i.e in wheel event). drawDot is just my mouse drawing handler, you will probably change it to whatever drawings you were doing (keeping in mind that you'd need to scale your high-quality drawing if you do handle user-relative actions).

Comment: tHank you, i managed to use your script in my project. Before closing this topic i need some help about a part of your script. Why did you use ratio_x and ration_y in setTransform? Why did you not use setTransform(2,0,0,2,0,0)?

Comment: @WMonteiro because you are not drawing the image with its real aspect ratio. But the full quality canvas is at the original image's AR. So we need to compensate this distortion between both canvases.

Comment: I give you an example because i don't understand. ratio_x = 1.5. So when i do offscreen.setTransform(ratio_x,0,0,ratio_y,0,0), i multiply the offscreen scale by ratio_x.

Comment: Your image is 3910 * 2610 px, but our output canvas is 500*500. The aspect ratio is not perserved, so we have to adjust it. Simply append the offscreen canvas in your document and check what it looks like.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help i fixed problem

Answer (score 0):

Here I removed a lot of your code to keep it super simple

```js
var src = "https://www.maisons-elytis-lyonouest.fr/wp-content/uploads/Maison-M.-ST-GENIS-LES-OLLIERES-HD-3.jpg";
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

var image = new Image();
image.addEventListener("load", function() {  
  context.imageSmoothingEnabled = true;
  context.mozImageSmoothingEnabled = true;
  context.webkitImageSmoothingEnabled = true;
  context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
});
image.src = src;

document.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', zoomIn);
document.addEventListener('mousewheel', zoomIn)


function zoomIn(e) {
  var z = 1
  context.drawImage(image, -1620/z, -1540/z, image.width/z, image.height/z);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" height="600" width="900"></canvas>
```

No blur as far as I can see...
You can try changing the `z = 1` to some thing a bit higher like 1.5 to see a different zoom.
The only thing I'm doing different is zooming to the width and height of the image

Comment: Thank you for your reply but i can't use image in drawImage(). Indeed, in my project i have others functions which allows me to create blur in canvas and if i zoom in with the image there will not be the blur.I will put update at top in a few moments

Comment: if i use image in drawImage() i can't save the blur, the new generated canvas should not be with blur